# Get the Headersize of a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there an elegant way to get the size of this area (or the amount of tabrows)?
[image]

I know I could just add the `ActualWidth` of each `TabItem` together and divide it by the `TabControl.Width`. But I wanted to know, if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: What do you want that for?

Comment: I'm making a drag&drop-able tabcontrol and I want to highlight the area where you can drop the tab.

Comment: Use Dragablz. Avoid trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'm doing this to learn something not to have the perfect outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `TabPanel` from the tab control’s visual tree. It has the name `HeaderPanel`, so you can access it pretty easily:

```
someTabControl.Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
    TabControl tc = (TabControl)s;
    FrameworkElement root = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(tc, 0);
    TabPanel headerPanel = root.FindName("HeaderPanel") as TabPanel;

    if (headerPanel != null) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(headerPanel.ActualHeight);
    }
};
```